# FFMPEG combining filter_complex and realtime processing

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

I am having trouble using both options. The goal is to use the `loop` filter to stream part of a video. This is the test command I've been running.

`ffmpeg.exe -re -i .\input.mkv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 20M -an -f mpegts -filter_complex loop=-1:100:200 udp://localhost:1222`

Getting rid of `filter_complex` will correctly stream the whole video, with ffmpeg processing it in realtime. But with `filter_complex` it no longer does, starting below the source framerate and then ramping up to maximum processing speed. And the loop is also broken, freezing the stream in place. How can this be achieved?

Comment: See the realtime filter. http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#realtime_002c-arealtime

Comment: @Gyan you should post this as an answer, you deserve the credit. `-filter_complex "loop=-1:100:200,realtime"` does the trick, thank you.